# Changing the background <body> background color switching css ids using recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm trying to change the body background color that flashes by id change using recursive function, that functions by even/odd condition check and continues by incrementing the supplied parameter after each excution. I'm executing this function using DOM level zero event handler on-click. I'm seeing some weird results.

Here is the html/css with its javascript code. Also see the comments that were put in the code, that explains other weird problems.

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <style>
        #style1 {
            background:red;
        }
        #style2 {
            background:black;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <input name="" type="button" value="Style Changer" id="button1" />
    <script>
        var button = document.getElementById("button1");
        var background = function (y) {
            alert(y); // results of background change or rest of the code only works if this alert is there which is what I don't really understand 
            if(y % 2 === 0) {
                alert(y); // weird result: this shows 2 for no reason.
                document.body.id = "style1"; // value supplied to the parameter y is 1 but taking the css property that suppose to take when the y is an even number. 
                var y = y + 1;
                background(y);
            } // End If
            else {
                document.body.id = "style2";
                var y = y + 1;
                background(y);
            } //End Else

        } // End of function
        button.onclick = function () {
            var x = 1;
            background(x);
        }

         // Another big problem: Last but not least remove all the alert function and it will not work as it worked when there were alerts in the code.
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: your code is formatted terribly, if you fix it you may find out why some of your problems are happening

Comment: Hi @Derek, Thank you very much for responding. You mean not organized properly or some thing else? Leaving efficiency for now I'm just doing some practicals playing around and I came across these weird results. Please help me. Please tell me which parts of the code should I re-format to be correct?

Comment: @Naresh - Actually your code works... http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/KuJNK/ I don't see where is the problem?

Comment: @Naresh - And also, try using your best friend web console to figure out where is the problem instead of using annoying `alert`s.

Comment: @Derek Thanks alot Derek...Yeah I'm now checking at jsfiddle.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I just finished checking at jsfiddle link you provided and I found you commented out the function recall.

Comment: This is a poor use of a recursive techniques. Why are you using recursion here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure what the actual problem is you want to solve.

But your code results in an infinite loop which in return results in an exception (check the console output):

```
Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

This is, because the recursive calls happen too fast. But when you use an alert, the code execution is basically paused as long as the alert box is shown.

You can counteract the code 'running too fast' by adding a small time delay:

```
var delay = 300;   // 300ms delay

var background = function(y){
    if( y%2 === 0){
        document.body.id = 'style1';
        setTimeout(function(){ background(y+1) }, delay);
    } else {
        document.body.id = 'style2';
        setTimeout(function(){ background(y+1) }, delay);
    }
}
```

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/D7pBx/

#### update 1: fast flashing

---

also note, that you can change the delay to be `0` which will result in a very fast flickering of the background, as you might intended.

#### update 2: stacking timeouts

---

As pointed out by @rdp a repeated clicking of the button would result in a stacking of the timeout calls. So if you want to prevent that from happening, you could always clear the previous timeout before creating a new one:

```
clearTimeout(t);
t = setTimeout(function(){ backgound(y+1) }, delay);
```

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/RuTxu/2/

Or you could only allow one setTimeout call at a time by setting a boolean:

```
if(busy) return;
busy = true;
setTimeout(function(){ 
    busy = false;
    backgound(y+1) 
}, delay);
```

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/RuTxu/3/

but of course, all of this depends on your specific use case

Answer (score 1):

This **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Amwe3/)** does what you seem to want, however, it doesn't  use recursion and it uses jquery.

### CSS

```
    .style0 {
        background-color: red;
    }
    .style1 {
        background-color: black;
    }
```

### Javascript/JQuery

```
    $(function () {
        var i = 0
        var background = function () {
            $("body").removeClass()
                .addClass("style" + i);

            i = ((i + 1) % 2); //To cycle from 0 to 1
        }

        var intervalID = undefined;
        $('#start').click(function () {
            if (intervalID != undefined) {
                clearInterval(intervalID);
            }
            intervalID = setInterval(background, 500);
        });
    });
```

### HTML

Notice the starting class style0 for the body tag.

```
    <body class="style0">
        <button id="start">Start</button>
    </body>
```

So, this may not be an acceptable answer for you but it does what it seems you wanted.

**Edit:** If you really want to use IDs instead of classes the following would more fit your question.

This **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KehdW/)** uses IDs. Updated code is below.

### CSS

```
    #style0 {
        background-color: red;
    }
    #style1 {
        background-color: black;
    }
```

### Javascript/JQuery

```
    $(function () {
        var i = 0
        var background = function () {
            $("body").attr("id", "style" + i);

            i = ((i + 1) % 2); //To cycle from 0 to 1
        }

        var intervalID = undefined;
        $('#start').click(function () {
            if (intervalID != undefined) {
                clearInterval(intervalID);
            }
            intervalID = setInterval(background, 500);
        });
    });
```

### HTML

Notice the starting id style0 for the body tag.

```
    <body id="style0">
        <button id="start">Start</button>
    </body>
```

Comment: And yeah I want to work on raw javascript for now, once I have strong foundation I'll move ahead to libraries/frameworks

Answer (score 0):

The reason it seems to "work" with `alert()`'s and not without is because the `alert()`'s slow down the recursive function execution so that it is perceivable. Otherwise this all "works", with or without alerts, you will however hit a `"Maximum call stack size exceeded"` error in Chrome for example simply because it's an infinite loop.

To get an idea of how fast it loops, see this demo where [I refactored your code and `document.write()` the loop number](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/8xTC2/). Loading that page it hits 15,000 in less than a second before it hits a call stack maximimum.

Comment: Hi @Marcel, Thank you very much. Yours was really informative. But how come the second alert in the code, shows 2 ? (.i.e before it's incremented).

Comment: @Naresh: the second alert is triggered when (y%2 === 0) is true. This is the case when y is even. So y was already incremented in the else-block when calling background(1) for the first time.

Comment: @Naresh: It's because 1 mod 2 isnt equal to 0 so it never hits that alert.